# Fancy box pop up required on click of fancy box popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a fancy box pop up message that has a button labelled 'continue'.  When I click on this button the fancy box closes.  What I want is this.  I want to click on the continue button and I want the fancy box to close (as it currently does) then I want another fancy box to pop up after that (a sign in screen).  I have code that makes the sign in screen pop up but don't know how to do this on the closing of the previous fancy box.  I have this code for the fancy box with the continue button

```
$.fancybox({
            'content': "<div style=\"border-width: 0px; width: 350px; height: 80px; color:#00285D; font-weight:bold;\">" + message + "<br/><br/>" + "<p class=\"center\"><a href=\"#\" onclick =\"parent.$.fancybox.close();\" class=\"btn-continue\">Continue</a></p>"
        });
```

I have this code for popping up the sign in screen (based on a link with an id of SignIn:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            CMF.pop('#SignIn',1010,459,0,0,'iframe');
        });
    </script>
```

The pop method looks like this:

```
// element, width, height, padding, margin, type, refresh(enabled if undefined)
    pop: function (el, w, h, p, m, i, r) {
        $(el).fancybox({
            width: w,
            height: h,
            padding: p,
            margin: m,
            type: i,
            scrolling: 'no',
            onClosed: function () {
                if( r == undefined)
                    parent.location.reload(true);                       
            }
        });
    } // fancybox
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Anyone?  I've already won the tumbleweed award, I don't think I can win it again.

Comment: a jsbin or jsfiddle always help people see what you're talking about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A demo page would help people answer your question much quicker saving both you and them time.   But anyway.. FancyBox apparently has a lot of "automatic" features since it seems to be made to be an easy image gallery solution.

Instead of calling:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

which doesn't even work in my example, because it existed in the current window, not window.parent so $.fancybox.close() would have been fine, if it was needed.  you just want fancy box to auto transition to the new content so just trigger the click event like this:

```
$('#SignIn').trigger('click');
```

be sure not to call close or it negates this click somehow...?  and yes, I too think it's stupid that FancyBox doesn't have a way of trigging the pop up without making you fake a "click" on the host item...

but straight from the horse's mouth: http://fancybox.net/blog (look under #6)

hope that helps -ck

Comment: +1 That's correct, so just modify the `onclick` call like `onclick =\"$('#SignIn').trigger('click');\"`

Comment: ckozl.  If you were here right now in front of me, I would give you such a big kiss.  This is great  - it worked perfectly.  Thanks a million.